# Array Code-Why Won't it Compile?

Tags: c++

Why is this code not compiling. The error message I am getting is

```
In function 'int main()':
10:15: error: cannot bind 'std::istream {aka std::basic_istream<char>}' lvalue to 'std::basic_istream<char>&&'
In file included from /usr/include/c++/4.9/iostream:40:0,
                 from 1:
/usr/include/c++/4.9/istream:872:5: note: initializing argument 1 of 'std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>& std::operator>>(std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>&&, _Tp&) [with _CharT = char; _Traits = std::char_traits<char>; _Tp = const char [8]]'
     operator>>(basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>&& __is, _Tp& __x)
     ^




#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int MAXTEMPS;
    int i, temp [MAXTEMPS];
    for(i=0; i< MAXTEMPS; i++) 
    {
        cout<<"Enter a Temperature:" ;
        cin>> "Temp[1]";
    }
    cout<<endl; 

    for(i=0; i<MAXTEMPS; i++)
    cout<<"Temperature "<<i<<" is" <<temp[i]<<endl; 
    return 0; 
}
```

Original code: [image]

Comment: @Cetshwayo Maybe you should simply enter and compile the original code should not you?:)

Comment: I spot several errors your code. First off: It's temp[1], not "temp[1]". "temp[1]" is a string. And in actuality I guess you want temp[i] and not temp[1].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to `cin` to a literal for some reason

```
cin >> "Temp[1]";
```

Get rid of the quotes, use correct capitalization, and use the index variable `i`.

```
cin >> temp[i];
```

Comment: Thanks yet it is still not working. Now instead of an error message I am getting nothing.

Comment: the error message is 6:26 "MAXTEMPS is used unitialized in the function[-Wunitialized]

Comment: Because `MAXTEMPS` is uninitialized, `int MAXTEMPS;`. You need to assign a value to it, like `int MAXTEMPS = 10`;

Comment: what is the difference between const int and int?

Comment: You are not allowed to modify a `const` variable, you can modify a non-`const` variable. It would really help you to sit down with an introductory C++ text, many of these things are covered.

Comment: Believe it are not I do have a text. I have a test on Monday. Horrible instructor etc..so I'm trying to do the best I can under the circumstances. Nonetheless, what do you mean I can not modify it, as oppose to what? I initialized the int MAXTEMPS = 5, and the program work. What difference does it make to use the const*?

Comment: @Cyber. Your comment is backwards :)

Comment: @chris `Cyber.insert(COFFEE)`

Answer (score 0):

First, the variable:

```
int MAXTEMPS;
```

is not initialized, as the original code shows, it needs to be equal to 5.

```
int MAXTEMPS = 5;
```

Second, you cant get input (cin) with a string literal, and you don't wont to use one index to get the input all so (temp[1]), so do this:

```
cin >> temp[i];
```

you should also consider using tabs when you enter a block (better to understand the code in my opinion)